# MySQL GROUP BY on Virtual Column with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

I've got a legacy DB structure inside `messages` for `mysql 5.7` that we need to pull out "the most recent message between 2 users"

The structure looks basically like...

```
id | from_id | to_id | message | created_at (datetime)
-------------------------------------------
1  |    1    |   2   |   xxx   | 05:00
2  |    2    |   1   |   xxx   | 07:00
3  |    3    |   1   |   xxx   | 08:00
4  |    1    |   2   |   xxx   | 10:00
```

So assuming the above data, the result I'd like to get would be... (although just a list of IDs is fine)

```
id | from_id | to_id | message | created_at (datetime)
-------------------------------------------
3  |    3    |   1   |   xxx   | 08:00
4  |    1    |   2   |   xxx   | 10:00
```

As theres no concept of "conversations" it's hard to group the messages into orderable chunks, so I've created a virtual column which concats the 2 user id to make a fake conversation id to query within using:

```
select *, ANY_VALUE(CONCAT(LEAST(from_id, to_id), "-", GREATEST(from_id, to_id))) conversation from messages;
```

This gives me:

```
id | from_id | to_id | message | created_at | conversation
----------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1    |   2   |   xxx   | 05:00      |     1-2
2  |    2    |   1   |   xxx   | 07:00      |     1-2
3  |    3    |   1   |   xxx   | 08:00      |     1-3
4  |    1    |   2   |   xxx   | 10:00      |     1-2
```

So as you can see the `conversation` column now provides a way to group the messages consistently.

The next "logical" step would be to `order by` them by `created_at` then `group by` the `conversation` column.

```
SELECT *, ANY_VALUE(CONCAT(LEAST(from_id, to_id), "-", GREATEST(from_id, to_id))) conversation
FROM messages
WHERE from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1
GROUP BY conversation
ORDER BY created_at desc;
```

However those of you who know MySQL better than me... will know this won't work and it seems to group them by the AUTO_INC column.

What's the correct method to do this? (also keeping an eye out for the sneaky WHERE I added)

I've created an SQL Fiddle with a sample of data to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4771d4/2/0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a greatest-n-per-group project: you want to filter rather than aggregate.

One option uses a subquery; `least()` and `greatest()` come handy to identify a conversation:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.id = (
    select m1.id
    from messages m1
    where 
        least(m1.from_id, m1.to_id) = least(m.from_id, m.to_id)
        and greatest(m1.from_id, m1.to_id) = greatest(m.from_id, m.to_id)
    order by created_at desc
    limit 1
)
order by created_at desc
```

Alternatively, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can implement the same logic with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        m.*, 
        row_number() over(
            least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id)
            order by created_at desc
        ) rn
    from messages m
) t
where rn = 1
order by created_at desc
```

Comment: Hi thanks - I've played with the first example you've provided - however this gives the data in the opposite order, so the newest message is last in the results, and if you change `created_at asc` then it's wrong in the other direction?

Comment: If you want to order the results of the query, then you can add an `order by` clause to the outer query, like `order by created_at desc`. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Ah that seems to make more sense, i'll try integrate and see what comes from it! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` on MySQL 8+, we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(from_id, to_id),
                                              GREATEST(from_id, to_id)
                                 ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM messages
)

SELECT id, from_id, to_id, message, created_at,
    CONCAT(LEAST(from_id, to_id), '-', GREATEST(from_id, to_id)) AS conversation
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, an aggregation approach can be used:

```
SELECT m1.id, m1.from_id, m1.to_id, m1.message, m1.created_at,
    CONCAT(LEAST(m1.from_id, m1.to_id), '-',
           GREATEST(m1.from_id, m1.to_id)) AS conversation
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        LEAST(from_id, to_id) AS from_id,
        GREATEST(from_id, to_id) AS to_id,
        MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY
        LEAST(from_id, to_id),
        GREATEST(from_id, to_id)
) m2
    ON LEAST(m1.from_id, m1.to_id) = m2.from_id  AND
       GREATEST(m1.from_id, m1.to_id) = m2.to_id AND
       m1.created_at = m2.max_created_at;
```

Comment: Hi, I've added mysql 5.7 now as a requirement  however I tried the "aggregation approach" however when i run it - it doesn't do any grouping at all e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4771d4/2/0